# Exception evaluating SpringEL expression for String array

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

While at spring boot <= 2.4.3 the below snippet worked fine.

```
<div class="link-red ddmenu" th:with="urls=${new String[]{'/'}}"
    th:classappend="${#arrays.contains(urls, #httpServletRequest.getRequestURI()) ? 'selected' : ''}">
    <a href="/" th:href="@{/}"> <i class="fa fas fa-home"></i>Home
    </a>
</div>
```

But after upgrading to 2.7.0, I am getting this parsing exception. What should I do to fix it?

```
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "new String[]{'/'}"
```

Or any related information for this break, available on any Thymeleaf's official site?

Comment: Just for info: It looks like this change was introduced in Spring Boot 2.6.4 - which, in turn, uses Thymeleaf 3.0.15. I do not get the error when I use Thymeleaf 3.0.14. I was not able to see anything obvious in the Thymeleaf (or Thymeleaf for Spring) release notes, and I don't have a solution, except to pass the string array data to your template from Java, instead of hard-coding it in the template.

Comment: All right. Thanks for looking into it and doing research on this @andrewJames

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interestingly enough, if you keep looking down the stack track you find this error at the bottom:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1005E: Type cannot be found 'String'
```

If I change the expression to:

```
th:with="urls=${new java.lang.String[]{'/'}}"
```

Everything works again for me (tested with Spring Boot starter 2.6.7).

Comment: Nice - this also fixes the problem if you have a pure-Thymeleaf application using version 3.0.15. This appears to be connected to Thymeleaf [issue 871](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/871). And that, in turn, mentions how this caused Thymeleaf-Spring [issue 293](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring/issues/293).